# Comma usage after the words well done

Tags: commas

Do I need to put a comma after done in the sentence

Well done indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Comma in this case is somewhat optional. It depends on how you want your readers to read your sentence. If you want them to pause before *indeed*, then you need a comma, otherwise you don't.

> Well done indeed, Sir.
>
> Well done indeed!
>
> It's very well done, indeed, boy.

Comment: Good answer. I'd just add that _Well done!_ is far more common than  _Well done indeed!_ (which sounds old-fashioned); emphasis is usually conveyed by _Very well done!_ though you will probably still here the occasional _Very well done indeed!_

Comment: @Noah:  How would you punctuate these words?:  "I say good show old chap!"  How about "I say:  good show, old chap!"?  Or, "I say!  Good show, old chap!"?  Just wondering.